# Sametime Issue - User not available in group even when online

Tags: ibm, ibm-domino, sametime

We have two sametime servers(Replica) located in London and Singapore.

We also have a group (PL_ALL) in which singapore users and london users are added.

When user log in via London server as host, singapore users are not shown in group PL_ALL. But at the same time there is another group PL_SG_ALL which is working correctly. (EX: User XX is there in both group but only visible in one group)

Any idea what could be the problem with PL_ALL group alone?

---

Sametime Server Version: 8.5.2 &
Sametime Client Version: 8.5.2

- Main Group - PL_ALL
- Sub Groups - PL_LN_ALL and PL_SG_ALL
- Subgroup under PL_LN_ALL  - PL_LN_Finance and more
- Subgroup under PL_SG_ALL - PL_SG_Finance and more
- User 1 - Is from Singapore and he is added in group PL_SG_Finance. He
  always connect to sametime client using Singapore sametime server as
  host
- User 2 - Is from London. He always connect to sametime client using
  London sametime server as host

Scenario 1: User 2 logs in to sametime and added PL_ALL and PL_SG_Finance group to his list. problem is he can see User1 listed under PL_SG_Finance but not under PL_ALL

Scenario 2:User 2 log in to sametine using Singapore sametime server as host. He case see User 1 in PL_ALL and also in PL_SG_Finance

I hope this is clear

Comment: Please provide the SW version of domino and Samtime used. Also, when you say "does not show in group", what do you mean exactly? Is this a group you added to your buddy list and the user is not showing up in there as available but it shows up as available in another group similar added? Does the user show up in the buddy list as available if you add him directly?

Comment: Sametime Server Version: 8.5.2 Sametime Client Version: 8.5.2

Comment: Are these servers in one ST Cluster? Which Server is User2 using in scenario 1 to log in?

Comment: Yes. Both servers are in cluster. User2 always uses London server and user1 always uses Singapore server. For verification purpose user2 logged in to Singapore server in scenario 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps outlined in Technote #1113464 [Troubleshooting issues with Sametime users not appearing online](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21113464)?

Especially, look at section 4 "If awareness involves clustered Sametime servers"

> IV. If awareness involves clustered Sametime servers:
>
> The communityConfig.txt file for the servers that are part of the cluster should look the same. If the clustered servers have different communityConfig.txt it is possible for **awareness between the clustered servers** (and additional Sametime servers) to **intermittently stop working**.
>
> In order to ensure that the clustered servers build the same communityConfig.txt, make sure they are replicating the names.nsf and that they have the same configuration for Directory Assistance.

Comment: The user is not completely not visible. He is visible under PL_SG_Finance. He he is not visible only under PL_ALL even though PL_SG_Finance is listed under PL_ALL

Comment: Pls. verify communityConfig.txt according to "IV. If awareness involves clustered Sametime servers"

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of known issues with nested groups and awareness in Sametime. Just Google for "sametime nested groups" and you will find a bunch of suggestions for solutions. One is to get a special hotfix from IBM for this issue. Check [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21586165) for an issue, that sounds like yours.